# Mongodb: How to lock a database in the thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mongodb

I am working on a mongodb project which need to lock db for reading in one thread. I am using this:

```
OperationContextImpl txn;
ScopedTransaction scopedXact(&txn, MODE_IS);
AutoGetDb autoDb(&txn, "db1", MODE_S);
Database* db = autoDb.getDb();
```

It works in the main thread as mongod but if I place it in another thread, I got this exception and mongodb exited abnormally:

```
Pure call handler invoked writing minidump diagnostic file xx.mdmp immediate exit due to invalid pure
```

I guess there should be something wrong about my usage for db lock. Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: What kind of exception? By the way, MonogDB does not support transactions.

Comment: Thanks. The error looks like this:Pure call handler invoked 
writing minidump diagnostic file xx.mdmp  
immediate exit due to invalid pure